# Can't get listview to update, tried most solutions

Tags: android, android-listview, android-activity

I have two activities.

Activity A: contains a listview and an 'edit' button.
Activity B: contains a form, and a save button.

When you start the app it opens Activity A.  Press the 'edit' button to open Activity B.  Fill out a form, press save and it stores this data in a SQlite 3 database, then kills Activity B.  This calls the onResume method for activity A.

In this onResume() method I'm trying to refresh the listView to display the new data that was just saved into it.

It currently looks like this;

```
    @Override
    protected void onResume() { 
        super.onResume();

        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();        
        lv.invalidate();
        System.out.println("onResume must have been called ");
    }
```

Why is my listview never refreshing?  It only displays the new data if I kill the activity completely and re-open it

Comment: Can you post a little bit more code? It's hard to tell what's wrong from this code.

Comment: Well the rest is just populating the listview in OnCreate from the SQlite database and that works fine.

Invalidate() work's on textviews.

Comment: How are you filling the array adapter? Are you giving it a List or array? You must be sure that the data structure that is backing the adapter gets updated (perhaps it does not have the sqllite database changes yet). Restarting the activity completely perhaps executes the select against the database and else.

Comment: I believe you may be right.  I'm probably just refreshing the adapter but it hasn't re-read from the SQlite DB to refresh the list that feeds the adapter.  I'll try this

Comment: That worked, thanks.  I've seen others who probably were doing the same thing so if you write that up as a answer I'll give you the green check :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be sure that the data structure that is backing the adapter gets updated (perhaps it does not have the sqllite database changes yet).

What is happening to you is that restarting the activity completely executes the select against the database and else.

Comment: Yep, I took just copied the code where I first populated the arrayAdapter, and placed that in front of the notifyDataSetChanged() and invalidate().  Works perfect now.